# Making a dialog box appear by clicking an image

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, dialog

I need to make an icon clickable in our webpage, then a dialog box should appear to confirm the action. With clicking yes some methods will start working, some stored procedures will work etc etc...

But sadly I have only this so far

```
<img src="../../../img/Edit_Icon.png">
```

When I searched about it, most of the results were about desktop applications. Am I searching something wrong or am I on a wrong track?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its easy... two options:

Either wrap your `img` by a `a` tag.

```
<a href="javascript:myFunction();"/> <img src="../../../img/Edit_Icon.png" /> </a>
```

or either add an onclick event on the image

```
<img src="../../../img/Edit_Icon.png" onclick="myFunction()" />
```

for the latter option, I would add a style to change the cursor to a "hand" in order to help the user understand "this is a clickable image"

```
<img src="../../../img/Edit_Icon.png" onclick="myFunction()" style="cursor: pointer;" />
```

JS CODE:

```
function myFunction(){
    var r = confirm("Press a button");
    if (r == true) {
        //your code to run
    } else {
        //code to run if cancel;
    }
```

[Live Example on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_confirm)

**Additionally**:
If you want something sexier then the browser's native dialog box, you can use a libraries...
e.g. [jQuery confirm.js](http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/)

Comment: Thanks for the response but I need to put a dialog box between image click and function. Function should work only if "Yes" is clicked on dialog box. How can I do it? Should I put the dialog box to the on click event?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<a href="#" id="pop"><img src="../../../img/Edit_Icon.png">Click Me</a>
```

JS Code :

```
$("#pop").on("click", function() {  
   //do something here 
});
```